# How to change an editbox from minutes to hours in Java

Tags: java, radio-button, editbox

I have a variable that is an integer array (*intArr*) containing three minute values. Then I have three edit boxes (*e1*, *e2*, *e3*), where e1 takes value intArr[0], e2 takes value intArr[1] and e3 takes value intArr[2]. I also have a radio button (one can either choose "*Show edit box time in minutes*" or "*Show edit box time in seconds*") connected to a variable.

How do I change the time in the edit boxes (which initially are in minutes) into hours, or in the opposite way from hours to minutes depending on which radio button has been chosen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to check the value of the radio button that has been selected:
You can either use:

`getText()` or `isSelected()`.

Then, depending on which one was selected, you can set the text of the edit box.
However, you need to get the value of the text field first.

You can use:

```
textField.getText();
```

Then you can parse it into an int using:

```
Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
```

Finally, you want to divide it by 60 and get the remainder of the divison:

```
int hours = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()) / 60; 
int minutes = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()) % 60;
```

You will also need to set the textfield to that new value:

```
textField.setText(hours + ":" + minutes);
```

Comment: I tried to do what you suggested, but I think I'm doing something wrong. When I run it and press radio button from inital value (minutes) to hours it actually works, but if I continue to press the button it will continue to change the edit box value until it reaches 0, then if I want to press back to minutes nothing happens. I'm doing the change from minutes to hours inside the radio button. Is that correct? Also, I tried to convert hours into minutes through Double.parseDouble(textField.getText()), and then int min = (int)((double)Double.parseDouble(textField.getText())*60.

Comment: Well, if you keep on clicking the radio button, it will keep on running the code that I described. What I suggest doing is created a boolean that keeps track of wether the textfield is in hours. Create an if/else statement based on the boolean. If it has already been set to hours, don't allow it to do it again.

Comment: Try the following: double hours = Double.parseDouble(textField.getText()));
  int min = (int) ((double)hours * 60);

Comment: When you only push the radio button once for minutes and then push the button once for hours it works! But if I push the button several times for example on hours the edit box value will decrease until it reaches 0, and if I push the button for minutes the edit box value will increase until it reaches some high value.

Comment: That's because it tries to convert it into into hours everytime you click on the radiobutton. You should set a variable: 'boolean hours=true'. If the values is true then you should change the texfield to hours, if it's false: only allow the textfield to change to minutes.